# Copy cells in spreadsheet by entering coordinates

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I have a large spreadsheet with 15346 rows

I enter a formula in B2, and want to copy it to B3:B15346. (I don't want a copy of the value in B2, I want an adjusted formula in each cell)

Is there a way to enter the range from the keyboard instead of by mouse or arrow/pgdown scrolling down, missing the target, scrolling up etc.

I just want to enter "copy(B2,B3:B15346)" or something to that effect.

I'm using libreoffice, but I hope there exists a generic solution.

Edit: The formula in question for cell D2 is `=LOOKUP($B2;$'hex rgb'.$A$2:$B$24712)`

D3 should then be `=LOOKUP($B3;$'hex rgb'.$A$2:$B$24712)`

Comment: Please check whether the [Name Box](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/02/06010000.html?DbPAR=CALC) is helpful.

Comment: If B3:B15346 cells are empty then simply double-click small square in right-down corner of B2, and the column cells must be autofilled.

Comment: Like @Emily said, you need a Name Box. Hotkey to select it **Ctrl+Shift+T**. That is, to copy B2 to the range B3:B15346, select B2, press Ctrl+C (copy B2), down arrow (select B3 - `B3` will be displayed in the Name box), Ctrl+Shift+T (cursor in Name Box before `B3`), End (cursor in Name Box after `B3`), type `:B15346` and press Enter (the specified range is selected and the cursor is on B3), Ctrl+V (insert formula), up arrow (deselect range, cursor in B2). To write down this sequence in words, many more buttons had to be pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by "just typing something" if you like, though not in the usual way folks solve Excel issues.

You can type the following, which will do your example, or edit it for other cells and ranges as needed:

`Range("b2").Copy  :  Range("b3:b15346").PasteSpecial`

You type that in something called the VBA "Immediate Window" (which has lots of purposes, but here you use it for your very own purpose.

To get to it, you can press `Alt-F11` to bring up the VBA editor and look for it on the screen. If you don't see it, press `Ctrl-G` to bring it up.

Essentially it is a way to run VBA commands that are of a nature to be able to run without the bigger VBA environment. So you could be complicated and run six commands, including declaring a local variable or two, but cannot use it to get a variable from some macro. So, simpled down some.

The above is actually two VBA commands (though someone versed in VBA could probably laugh and make it a single one) and you could do them one at a time or type out two lines, then go back to each and "step through" them by pressing `Enter` on each line. But if you use that `:` in between separate commands, you can write them all on a single line and just press `Enter` once, when done, to make the magic happen.

Don't be disturbed that the last bit says `.PasteSpecial`... in VBA it is not the same command that it would be "cell-side". It will paste the formula, not the values, etc.

For years, after I first thought I'd learn VBA but never had the time, I kept a Word document with handy snippets like the above so I could do things that vexed formula folks. (Much of my work at that time was me using my own spreadsheets, not writing them for users so I could have the manual aspect that no user would ever countenance.)

Point is, until I read a tip from Philip Treacy, it never occurred to me to fill huge ranges through it. (Sigh...) This would be a use of his practice of doing so.

You can use the Immediate Window for a LOT of things, and get the benefits of VBA even with spreadsheets that are not allowed (by the boss) to have macros. (You could actually write some for such spreadsheets and copy them out to a Word document and paste back in the next time you use the spreadsheet, never saving it with them, but I've found over time, I really only use them like this, a line or two to do some hard to do formula-based thing.)

When I use them all the time in a given spreadsheet, I make a Named Range and in the `Refers to:` box, I paste the line, no beginning `=`, just the line. Excel neatly saves that, adding the `=` and some doublequotes. Put those in yourself and it refuses. Go figure. Then when I need it, I don't have to open another document, just go to the Name Manager and copy out the formula there, and remove that `=` and the wrapper doublequotes after pasting in the Immediate Window, then run it. Takes a tenth of the time it took to read this paragraph.

But that's a really simple way ("old hat" not some worrisome thing after just a few times doing it) to achieve many things by just typing.

Also, finding the command to do any particular thing is not hard via Google. Usually.

Comment: This is really interesting - however, I'm using libreoffice calc, but I was hoping there would be a generic method, which worked in several spreadsheet versions.
It seems there's some VBS in libreoffice, so I'll have to look for libreoffice calc vba specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not really mention your end goal or the specific formula, but only stated that a formula is applied in column B, it is a bit difficult to judge. However, one approach would be to use a formulaic way. For example, if you wanted to apply a specific function or formula (e.g., `left`) to each row in column A, you could use the following approach:

```
=LEFT(INDEX($A:$A,2,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A),1),3)
```

This formula is very flexible and creates the corresponding array from the second row up to as many rows as you have values, which is controlled by `counta`. You have to be a bit careful if you have missing values, because the formula only counts non-empty rows. But you can either remedy this by specifying a running ID in one of the columns, or by specifying the number of rows you want to have with your formula. Of course, the formula is not dependent on the function `left`, but only served as an illustration, you can also simply insert it into your own formula:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,2,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A),1)
```

Comment: I thought it was obvious that I wanted the same functionality as when copying b2 to b3:b15346 by mouse-pulling: a new adjusted formula in each cell

Comment: Yes, but depending on the specific use case, this can be achieved with the described approach. In fact, the behaviour would be the same as copying the formula by mouse-pulling. In this approach, the formula in each cell is adjusted implicitly, but the array is created automatically.

Comment: No, it didn't really solve my problem, but It's not a frequent problem for me, so I'll just do it the manual way. Appearently the macro method doesn't work for libreoffice

Answer (score -1):

1. Goto cell B15346. (no need to scroll, just enter "B15346" on the cell address box, near A1 @ top left)
2. type =$B$2 in the cell B15346
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> cell B15346
4. Then (with cell B15346 still selected) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> (the selection will go upto B1)
5. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> still pressed, press <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> twice (the selection will go upto B3).
6. (after letting go <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> ) n press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
7. Done

Please share if it works/not..

Comment: It seems to me that in step 5 the CTRL button is not needed, only Shift and an arrow

Comment: This does not copy the formula, it makes all the other cells have the value if B2
Each cess should have it's own formula, adjusted for the change in row.
So B2=SIN(A2), B3=SIN(A3) etc

Comment: @JohnSUN correct. Thanks . | "Each cess should have it's own formula" was not mentioned in the question. I'm answering based on "copy it to B3:B15346" line.. | Since u had mentioned an example here.. just replace `=$B$2` with `=sin(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1))` will do. everything else the same. | note : hv a read on how indirect() n offset() works, I base the new formula to be : _give me the Sin value for the one cell left side this one_